# python: how to override SimpleHTTPServer to show timestamp in directory listing?

Tags: python

I am using

```
 python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

as a very simple web server for internal users to access data files on a test server.

The default listing of `SimpleHTTPServer`  is very simple. It only shows file links.

How can I make it to show the file timestamp as well? I am happy to write a custom class to extend `SimpleHTTPServer`

I am using python 2.4.3 at the moment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could subclass `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`:

```
import cgi, os, SocketServer, sys, time, urllib
from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
from StringIO import StringIO

class DirectoryHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def list_directory(self, path):
        try:
            list = os.listdir(path)
        except os.error:
            self.send_error(404, "No permission to list directory")
            return None
        list.sort(key=lambda a: a.lower())
        f = StringIO()
        displaypath = cgi.escape(urllib.unquote(self.path))
        f.write('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">')
        f.write("<html>\n<title>Directory listing for %s</title>\n" % displaypath)
        f.write("<body>\n<h2>Directory listing for %s</h2>\n" % displaypath)
        f.write("<hr>\n<ul>\n")
        for name in list:
            fullname = os.path.join(path, name)
            displayname = linkname = name
            date_modified = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(fullname))
            # Append / for directories or @ for symbolic links
            if os.path.isdir(fullname):
                displayname = name + "/"
                linkname = name + "/"
            if os.path.islink(fullname):
                displayname = name + "@"
                # Note: a link to a directory displays with @ and links with /
            f.write('<li><a href="%s">%s - %s</a>\n'
                    % (urllib.quote(linkname), cgi.escape(displayname), date_modified))
        f.write("</ul>\n<hr>\n</body>\n</html>\n")
        length = f.tell()
        f.seek(0)
        self.send_response(200)
        encoding = sys.getfilesystemencoding()
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html; charset=%s" % encoding)
        self.send_header("Content-Length", str(length))
        self.end_headers()
        return f

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", 8000), DirectoryHandler)
print "serving at port", 8000
httpd.serve_forever()
```

This might look like a lot of work, but really I'm just adding one line to the `list_directory` method:

```
    date_modified = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(fullname))
```

...and then adding it to the directory listing output.

Comment: Just realise the var 'linkname' is not quite right there. It should be: linkname = os.path.join(displaypath, displayname). Thanks for the solution again.

Comment: `httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", 8000), DirectoryHandler) `
Should be:
`BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(server_address, DirectoryHandler)`
With an extra import of BaseHTTPServer at the top of the file